# Java, Unicode, UTF-8, and Windows Command Prompt

Tags: java, windows, unicode, utf-8, command-prompt

I have a jar file that is supposed to read a UTF-8 encoded file—that I wrote in a text editor under Windows—and display the characters to the screen. Under OS X and Linux this works flawlessly. I'm having a bit of trouble getting it to work under Windows though... I've defined a reader and writer like so:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(file, "UTF8");

PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF8");
```

I've also changed the command prompt font to `Lucida Console` and the character encoding to UTF-8 with `chcp 65001`, in that order.

Now, when I run `java -jar Read.jar file.txt`, the prompt splurges this out.

```
áéí
ñóú
[]óú
[]
```

However, if I run `type file.txt`, the prompt correctly displays the file's contents.

```
áéí
ñóú
```

I've tried saving my file with and without BOM, but that hasn't made a difference. (UTF-8 doesn't even need BOM because it's lack of endianness, correct?) I've tried compiling with `javac -encoding utf8 *.java`, but the same thing happens.

I'm out of ideas now. Anyone care to help?

Comment: If you redirect the output to a file, is the output file the same as the input file?  If not, what differs?

Comment: Are you using write(buffer,0,bytesread) to output the data?

Comment: Redirecting via `type file.txt > file2.txt` produces the exact same file with all the correct characters.

Comment: And the `write` method is to write to a file, is it? I wrote the input file using a text editor, not through the code.

Comment: I meant when you are writing it to console using printwriter to write to console , you use the read buffer rgt! Now are you doing something like this byte[] byteBuff = new byte[10] ;
  int bread = file.read(byteBuff);
  writer.write(byteBuff, 0, bread) ;  //

Comment: Don't trust the Windows command prompt. It doesn't really work with utf8. So if you want to see what your file contains, don't just print it to stdout. Open the file in an editor which can handle the encoding you expect, or perhaps print out each byte as a hex value or base64-encoded

Comment: The only reliable way I've found of emitting Unicode is [via native code](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/java-unicode-on-windows-command-line.html).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Code page 65001 is broken. The MS C runtime stdio functions return inaccurate counts of bytes read and written when run under 65001, which leads to strange behaviours like this one.

It's not fixable - you can't reliably use the Windows console for Unicode I/O from applications that use the C stdlib byte-I/O functions (which includes Java). You can hack it by calling the Win32 API function WriteConsoleW to get Unicode content directly to the Console, but then you have to worry about detecting when stdout actually is a console (not redirected to file).

This is a long-standing source of woe which MS shows no interest in fixing.

Comment: I read support was broken somewhere else online, but refused to believe it. Sigh. Unfortunately, I think you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Looks it could be you newline characters. When i make the newline chars in the standard english language ISO-8859-1 i use a char[] array because windows characters '\r' and'\n' and UNIX/Linux are only \r as the newline character. Win 4 bytes , unix 2 bytes.
A not, in the API docs for character converter classes, the encoding conversion system can have spurious bytes left over to throw away dependent the encodings and character size requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use BufferReader to read your file like this;

```
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(
                  new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but the prompt remained screwy.