# € Symbol Java Unicode

Tags: java, unicode

Trying to print € symbol to screen using Unicode.

The following code displays OK in Eclipse but using the windows command line I get:

```
pound = ú
euro = Ç
```

Code:

```
class Test{      
public static void main(String[] args) {
       String euro = "\u20ac";
       String pound = "\u00a3";

        System.out.println("pound = " + pound);
        System.out.println("euro = " + euro);
    }
}
```

Why is this? Ctrl+alt+$ shows € command line so the symbol is there?

Comment: which platform? [Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388490/995714), [How to Output Unicode Strings on the Windows Console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3130979/995714), [Output unicode strings in Windows console app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2492077/995714)

Comment: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html

Comment: Thank you. chcp 1252 worked for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is character encoding and why should I bother with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding-and-why-should-i-bother-with-it)

Comment: Related (but perhaps outdated?): [Java, Unicode, UTF-8, and Windows Command Prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11927518/1468366)

Answer (score -1):

Following worked for me:

- Switch the console from the raster font to a Unicode TrueType font.
- Type chcp 1252 to switch code page.

Comment: Do not use any code pages other than 65001. Unicode is the way to go

Answer (score -1):

Check the hexadecimal value for windows or linux or whatever operating system it's a little bit different here is for windows.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850)